# Origin of "Amurrica"

Tags: etymology, orthography

I can't remember the president or politician who famously pronounced America as "Amurrica".  I hope someone else can.  As in

> This is Amurrica.

Also, is there a standard, or at least better, way to notate it?

**Edit:**  Would appreciate first citation and alternative spellings.

Comment: The following is also slang for America: [murica](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/murica) and [Amurica](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Amurica)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That, I believe, was Lyndon Baines Johnson. "Mah fellow Amurricans."

Comment: With fellow-Texan George W. Bush it sounded more like "Murka."

Comment: Could you provide a linked reference for the non-American folk among us :). Please?